# Tool for creating spring jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Is there any 'tool' or 'plugin for STS' to directly create spring-form jsp? Is there any drag and drop facility for spring form creation so that I can develop applications rapidly?

Comment: For What purpose you want this tool?please explain us more so that we can help you...

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that automatic create a JSP for a Controller, or are you looking for a tool that is a bit like a GUI designer fpr JSP?

Comment: Odd.  This question has attracted 2 comments with 2 questions (basically suggesting the question is unclear), yet it has 4 up-votes.  -1 to add some sanity.

Comment: This is not the place to request a plugin in STS. And you forgot to add tag sts-springsourcetoolsuite.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the NetBeans IDE for Java EE here: http://netbeans.org/downloads/